# migrating to RAID1

Tags: boot, gparted, raid

my computer was polluted a bit when I upgraded Ubuntu to 16.04.1 from 15.10, and not everything works (I have to use xterm instead of gnome-terminal, etc.)  I plan to fix the 'pollution' by doing a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04.1, copying my home directory, and installing missing packages.  Currently the computer has a 500 GiB drive, which is running out of space.  I bought two 2 TiB drives, which I plan to use to replace the 500 GiB drive; the two drives will be in a RAID1 configuration.  Here's my plan:

1. Make the 500 GiB drive unbootable.
2. Shut down, unplug the 500 GiB drive, and plug in both 2 TiB drives.
3. Boot to the Server install DVD, install the server edition of Ubuntu, and have the installer configure the two 2 TiB drives as a RAID1 array.  Install the `ubuntu-desktop` package to make the system a Desktop system.
4. Shut the system down, plug the 500 GiB drive back in.  Boot.
5. Mount the 500 GiB drive, and copy my home folder (~) from the 500 GiB drive to the RAID1 array.
6. Install packages that are missing; just the ones I really need, of course.

My question is, how do I make the 500 GiB drive unbootable, so that when I boot the system with both the old 500 GiB drive and the 2 TiB RAID1 array present, the computer knows to boot to the 2 TiB RAID1 array?  Is it as simple as using `gparted` to remove the boot flag from the first partition?

Also, can anyone see any holes in my plan?

Comment: You don't need to "make the 500GiB drive unbootable". Simply assure the boot device is the array in BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: The plan us to unplug the 500 GB so you don't need to remove the boot flag which you can do with gparted if legacy at least. Once you initialize mdadm with the two raid disks they become the boot with Ubuntu installed and no knowledge of 500 GB. Later when you plug it in you'll probably have to mount it with Nautilus to copy your files off.

Comment: Oh yeah I also have a bricked 500 GB drive in my second drive bay and a new 240 GB in SSD in laptop drive bay 1 now and did similar to your plan myself.